# c# Project reference

Tags: c#, project-reference, dll-reference

Reading [MSDN's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45.aspx), I was left uncertain.

**Setting:**
I have project A referencing some dll X, and project B project-referencing project A, and requiring dll X as well.

Would I need to add a reference to dll X to both projects, or would the project reference do that for me?

Comment: if you want to use X dll types directly in project B then you will need to add reference there as well

Comment: Depends on the kind of DLL.  If it is normal .NET assembly and gets copied by the B project to B's output directory then, yes, it will automatically get copied as well.  Do consider not asking for a manual but describing what you actually see happening, saves everybody a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to add a reference to `X` when classes, methods, etc. of `X` are made available through `A`.

If there is no public use of `X` in `A`, you don't need to reference it (although you would need it in your `bin` folder.

Comment: What do you mean by made available and public use? Use in public classes and functions within A?

Comment: When it exposes the member through a method for example, so: `public void DoSomething(ClassFromX x)`.

Comment: So it is something like a transitive closure. If I reference X, and X contains a property of type Y, which contains a property of type Z etc., I will get Y and Z as well. (And all types they contain recursively)